# SQL (Oracle) : how to improve a select ordered by x desc

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

I have a huge log table in a db. There is an index on the log_id and the log_date.

When I query logs in reverse order, it takes 'forever' to complete. 
While I do the same query with no order, the answer is immediate.

How can I tune the table/improve the query to have a quick(er) reverse select ?

Edit: the query (sorry the query was obvious in my mind (and in Florin too !):

```
select * from logs ordered by log_date desc
```

Some metrics:

There are around 40 millions of rows in the table

```
select * from logs where log_id < 500
```

--> fetched in 0.032 seconds

```
select * from logs where log_id < 500 order by log_time desc;
```

--> fetched in around 20 seconds

$max is a the max log_id and it has been retrieved in another query

```
select * from logs where log_id > ($max - 500);
```

--> fetched in around 16 seconds

```
select * from logs where log_id > ($max - 500) order by log_time desc;
```

--> fetched in around 16 seconds

My question is how to improve all the queries that takes too many seconds too execute.

@Florin
With a 'where' clause narrowing the log in time `(where log_time >= truncate(sysdate))` I have good performance, but I need to be able to select logs for a long time period or for a range far in the past. In this case the query is still quite slow (like 20s).

Comment: Look into Reverse Key Indexes [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14574/5743) on dba.se and possibly IOTs for the "serious" `change the DB` answers. There's probably a simpler way though. Have you considered a Materialized View?

Comment: If you don't supply the query, or the schema, are you expecting us to guess or be psychic?

Comment: @Ben, Reverse Key indexes are exactly the opposite of what will help in this situation (RK indexes are not ordered in reverse order, the key values themselves are byte-reversed which effectively scatters the values around the index). An ordinary index can be traversed in either direction by Oracle.

Comment: @Dems, not psychic, I was expecting you to be smart ;) (I'm joking, I felt like an idiot to have not provided the query)

Comment: `select * from logs where log_id < ($max - 500);` should be `select * from logs where log_id > ($max - 500);`

Comment: and I guess `select * from logs where log_id < 500 ` returns maaaany rows. That's why `order by` is slowing de query.

Comment: I have fixed the query, the error came from copy paste (the real queries used to test contains awful names :) ).
About the 'where log_id < 500' returning too much rows, I'm not sure that returning 500 rows is a lot. Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from log_table 
where log_date >= trunc(sysdate)  --current_day
order by log_id desc, log_date desc
```

This will do a range scan in the log_date index, and will retrieve a day of rows from log_table, not the entire table.
After this the sort will be faster because will have few rows to sort.

**UPDATE:**
Another things you can do:

- Make the log_date column `NOT NULL`(this may change the optimiser to
  use the index);
- use a `/*+parallel(logs 8)*/` hint (if you dont shoot
  this query too often and just need the results quick in your db tool. And if you have many processors :) )
- you can partition the table in a monthly manner or even more detailed.

Comment: Thanks Florin, yes this is improving the query a lot. But I need to be able to perform search in time (last 10 days, last month, between the 20th and the 25th 5 monthes ago... And in this case the queries are still really too slow

Comment: I understand, but when you want to view the entire history is a special case, when you want to analyse something. In a normal use of log you want to see what happened last night or yesterday. Why do you want to always 'select * from logs ordered by log_date desc`?

Comment: No I don't want to select always the entire history. I was just surprised to see that a simple query in reverse order was so slow. But the fact that querying within a date range at the end of the table is slow (logs are usually searched on last few days) is quite annoying. Is there any way to tell Oracle that this table will be accessed on a reverse scheme ?

Comment: see my another hints in the answer. Oracle make a lot of work to sort the data.

Comment: Thank you very much.I have never heard about the hints. I was aware of partitioning, but I never did that before (you can guess that managing db is not my primary skill). I'm reading about range partitioning, but it is looking quite subtle (http://www.rittmanmead.com/2008/09/investigating-oracle-11g-interval-partitioning/).